# Systemd doesn't seem to respect After= dependency?

Tags: systemd, nixos

I have a PostgreSQL server (`postgresql.service`) and a basic shell script (`mobilizon-postgresql.service` that is run to provide some assertions on the database to a third service (Mobilizon).

So naturally, `mobilizon-postgresql.service` is configured with an `After=` dependency for `postgresql.service`:

```
# systemctl show mobilizon-postgresql.service | grep After=
After=basic.target system.slice systemd-journald.socket sysinit.target postgresql.service
```

Though after a reconfiguration of the system (which didn't touch these dependencies), I'm seeing the following behaviour in the logs:

```
1677672119.103035 myserver systemd[1]: Starting Mobilizon PostgreSQL setup...
...
1677672119.153192 myserver systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Server...
```

So, `mobilizon-postgresql.service` is started **before** the startup of `postgresql.service`.

```
1677672119.279742 myserver mobilizon-postgresql-start[329444]: psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
1677672119.279742 myserver mobilizon-postgresql-start[329444]:         Is the server running locally and accepting
1677672119.279742 myserver mobilizon-postgresql-start[329444]:         connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.543>
1677672119.283558 myserver systemd[1]: mobilizon-postgresql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
1677672119.283707 myserver systemd[1]: mobilizon-postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
1677672119.289678 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Mobilizon PostgreSQL setup.
```

So of course, `mobilizon.postgresql` can't setup a connection to the db.

```
1677672119.503881 myserver postgres[329458]: [329458] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 11>
1677672119.512541 myserver postgres[329458]: [329458] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
1677672119.512863 myserver postgres[329458]: [329458] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
1677672119.519498 myserver postgres[329458]: [329458] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
...
1677672119.871989 myserver systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Server.
```

Only later the `postgresql.service` is reported to be fully started.

This behaviour goes completely against my understanding of `After=`. From `systemd.unit(5)`:

> If unit foo.service contains the setting Before=bar.service and both units are being started, bar.service's start-up is delayed until foo.service has finished starting up.

Am I having wrong assumptions here?

Systemd version is 251.12, Distro is NixOS 22.11

Answer (score 0):

What does systemd mean by "finished starting up"? `man systemd.unit` says

> for service
> units start-up is considered completed for the purpose of
> Before=/After= when all its configured start-up commands have been
> invoked and they either failed or reported start-up success.

So you need to look in the postgresql service file to see if it is doing something like forking and putting its pid in a file, or using `sd_notify()` in its code to signal "ready". It's not very useful.

Sadly, the easy way round this is to make the `mobilizon-postgresql`
service wait for the Unix domain socket to exist, using `inotifywait` or
similar, or add `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=1` to retry until
success.

Systemd's idea of how things should work is that you create a socket unit, and whenever anyone tries to open that socket, you launch a program. In this case, by starting your script, which opens the socket, it launches postgresql.

Comment: That was my first suspicion, that PostgreSQL and systemd have different opinions of what constitutes a "started" service. But in this case, systemd itself reports PostgreSQL as "started" way after it does things that should only happen after a started service? See the last log line in the question.

Comment: @erictapen: More specifically, PostgreSQL doesn't _accurately report_ to systemd when its service should be considered "started". Which version are you using? Postgres 15.2 on Arch seems to support sd_notify() readiness notifications, as its .service unit has Type=notify (though that doesn't guarantee that it was programmed to invoke sd_notify() at the correct time). Does your postgresql.service use Type=notify, Type=forking, or Type=simple? Does it invoke postgres directly, or does it somehow go through a wrapper init.d script?

Comment: Mh, I think my PostgreSQL *does* accurately report to systemd when it's started? See the last log snippet, it reports ports and sockets being open and then systemd states that it "Started PostgreSQL Server".
My problem is that systemd just doesn't seem to care about startup state of PostgreSQL and starts the unit nonetheless?

Answer (score 0):

(Showing complete units would be helpful, BTW)

`After=` without a `Wants=` or `Requires=` does not have the effect you think.
As `man systemd.unit` describes (on `Before=, After=`):

> Note that *those settings are independent of and orthogonal to the
> requirement dependencies* as configured by `Requires=`, `Wants=`,
> `Requisite=`, or `BindsTo=`. It is a common pattern to include a unit
> name in both the `After=` and `Wants=` options, in which case the unit
> listed will be started before the unit that is configured with
> these options.

(Emphasis added by the poster)